# Beautiful Soup replaces < with &lt;

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I've found the text I want to replace, but when I print `soup` the format gets changed. `<div id="content">stuff here</div>` becomes `&lt;div id="content"&gt;stuff here&lt;/div&gt;`. How can i preserve the data? I have tried `print(soup.encode(formatter="none"))`, but that produces the same incorrect format.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open(index_file) as fp:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fp,"html.parser")

found = soup.find("div", {"id": "content"})
found.replace_with(data)
```

When I print `found`, I get the correct format:

```
>>> print(found)
<div id="content">stuff</div>
```

`index_file` contents are below:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <head>
    Apples 
 </head>
 <body>

   <div id="page">
    This is the Id of the page

  <div id="main">

     <div id="content">
       stuff here
     </div>
  </div>
 footer should go here
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In which format your index_file is saved? Can you show a part of it? (I don't have any problem with a .html file and the exact samecode)

Comment: the file is saved as `.html`.  If I print `found` everything is ok.  If I print `soup` then the `found`  which I just replaced is displaying the `&lt;div id="content"&gt;stuff`

Comment: are those exact lines you are trying to execute? because I tried to load the same content in `BeautifulSoup` and no such issue exist.

Comment: if it's not exactly the same then share the exact same code and it's output

Comment: What's inside the variable data? @user3525290

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `found` object is not a Python string, it's a [`Tag`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#tag) that just happens to have a nice string representation. You can verify this by doing

```
type(found)
```

A `Tag` is part of the hierarchy of objects that Beautiful Soup creates for you to be able to interact with the HTML. Another such object is [`NavigableString`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring). `NavigableString` is a lot like a string, but it can only contain things that would go into the content portion of the HTML.

When you do

```
found.replace_with('<div id="content">stuff here</div>')
```

you are asking the `Tag` to be replaced with a `NavigableString` containing that literal text. The only way for HTML to be able to display that string is to escape all the angle brackets, as it's doing.

Instead of that mess, you probably want to keep your `Tag`, and replace only it's content:

```
found.string.replace_with('stuff here')
```

Notice that the correct replacement does not attempt to overwrite the tags.

When you do `found.replace_with(...)`, the object referred to by the name `found` gets replaced in the parent hierarchy. However, the name `found` keeps pointing to the same outdated object as before. That is why printing `soup` shows the update, but printing `found` does not.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  Not sure I would've figured that out.  Was headed towards a regex solution.

Comment: @user3525290. I understand that feeling. Given what you know now, I'd recommend going back over the beautiful soup docs I linked to from scratch. They're quite good if you already have an idea of what they will say :)