# Insert HTML into an element with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

When I try to insert the following HTML into an element

```html
<div class="frontpageclass"><h3 id="feature_title">The Title</h3>... </div>
```

`bs4` is replacing it like this:

```html
<div class="frontpageclass">&lt;h3 id="feature_title"&gt;The Title &lt;/h3&gt;... &lt;div&gt;</div>
```

I am using `string` and it is still messing up the format.

```
with open(html_frontpage) as fp:
   soup = BeautifulSoup(fp,"html.parser")

found_data = soup.find(class_= 'front-page__feature-image')
found_data.string = databasedata
```

If I try to use `found_data.string.replace_with` I get a NoneType error. `found_data` is of type tag.

[similar issue but they are using div, not class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52040260/beautiful-soup-replaces-with-lt)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Setting the element `.text` or `.string` causes the value to be HTML-encoded, which is the right thing to do. It ensures that the text you insert will appear 1:1 when the document is displayed in a browser.

If you want to insert *actual* HTML, you need to insert new nodes into the tree.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# always define a file encoding when working with text files
with open(html_frontpage, encoding='utf8') as fp:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, "html.parser")

target = soup.find(class_= 'front-page__feature-image')

# empty out the target element if needed
target.clear()

# create a temporary document from your HTML
content = '<div class="frontpageclass"><h3 id="feature_title">The Title</h3>...</div>'
temp = BeautifulSoup(content)

# the nodes we want to insert are children of the <body> in `temp`
nodes_to_insert = temp.find('body').children

# insert them, in source order
for i, node in enumerate(nodes_to_insert):
    target.insert(i, node)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the messing format, there are only & lt; and & gt; corresponding to '<' and '>'. Just replace all of them should work.

eg. suppose beautifulsoup inserts html tag into soup1 variable with messing format:
a=str(soup1).replace(& lt;,'<').replace(& gt;,'>'); print(a)

In real code, one should put & lt; inside ' ' and no space in between. (Here, web displays & lt; with no space same as <)

So variable a should work with correct format.